# diagonal text in math mode w/ vertical equality

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, equations, symbols, typography

The goal is a code where one can label elements in math mode in the following way:

[image: label]

without having to manually position each letter of each word as a node in tikz. Preferably, other than the stacks plugin, tikz does not have to be invoked, but no problem if it is in the end.

The two types of diagonals as a macro is the challenging bit. A macro or something is needed to convert a word in

```
\macro_name{word}
```

to a diagonal, growing right from the top, or growing left from the bottom, like in the two examples above. Then it can be used, w/ [Steven Segletes's tabstackengine package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabstackengine) in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\stackMath
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\scriptstyle#1}
\def\req{\protect\rotatebox{90}{$\scriptstyle=$}}
\def\rne{\protect\rotatebox{90}{$\scriptstyle\ne$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\setstackgap{L}{.6\baselineskip}\setstacktabulargap{0pt}\TABbinary
\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{
&\mathclap{alpha}& &\mathclap{beta}&\\ &\req& &\req& \\ (&A& , &B&) \hspace{1mm}= \hspace{1mm} F\\
 &\rne&\\ &\mathclap{(D , B)}&}
\]

% BTW, for some reason, tex cannot compile if <<\mathclap{(D , B)}>> is replaced with <<\mathclap{\overbrace{(D , B)}}>> or <<\mathclap{\underbrace{(D , B)}}>> but this is a different question, no?

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I just noticed that it looks strange if only vertical spacing is controlled. There needs to be a parameter to space the letters horizontally in each diagonal. Is that possible? (When writing by hand, I observe the letters are placed CLOSER together horizontally to make it more readable in addition to the vertical displacement which is already presently controlled in the answer below.)

Comment: It would be easier to use \rotatebox from the graphics package.  You could create a command to place each letter with a linearly increasing or decreasing height using \raisebox.

Comment: Spacing will probably *never* look good with variable-width upright characters along a diagonal. This is because your eye expects alignment of the bottom center of each character along the diagonal, *and* equal spacing along the vertical *and* variable spacing along the horizontal: clearly, there's a contradiction. Either rotate the characters or use fixed-width font.

Comment: None of the answers give you satisfaction ? Is there something to achieve ?

Comment: I made a bounty to reward the answer. Was traveling so I didn't get to it sooner. I think I can only award the bounty after 23 hours. Great answers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't say I'm enamored of the look, but it does the first form you mention.  The other can be done if you really want it, still.  The key for the diagonal text is a recursive use of `\brlap`, which is a bottom-right lap, with the vertical offset of each lap scaled back, currently, to 38% of `\baselineskip`.

EDITED to allow horizontal kerning between letters to be set by `\myhkern` and vertical offset of successive letters to be set by `\myvgap`.  In addition, `\diagunder` takes an optional argument (default =) defining the character rotated and placed below the first argument.  Set as `[]` in order to begin the labels at the height where the default `=` sign would have been.

REEDITED to provide both `\diagunder` and `\diagover`, with identical syntax.  Note that the diagonal text retains its height, but is perceived to have zero width, so that you will notice that `(A,B)` line up vertically in both over and under stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine, graphicx}
\def\myhkern{.8pt}
\def\myvgap{.38\baselineskip}
\def\stacktype{L}
\newcommand\diagunder[3][\raisebox{-5pt}{$=$}]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax%
    \stackunder{$#2$}{\expandafter\angletext#3\relax}%
  \else
    \stackunder{$#2$}{\stackunder[.7\baselineskip]{\rotatebox{90}{$#1$}}{%
    \expandafter\angletext#3\relax}}%
  \fi
}
\def\angletext#1#2\relax{\small\setstackgap{L}{\myvgap}%
  \kern\myhkern#1\angletextB#2\relax}
\def\angletextB#1#2\relax{%
  \brlap{\kern\myhkern#1\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\angletextB#2\relax\fi}%
}
\newcommand\diagover[3][\raisebox{-5pt}{$=$}]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax%
    \stackon{$#2$}{\expandafter\upangletext#3\relax}%
  \else
    \stackon{$#2$}{\stackon[.9\baselineskip]{\rotatebox{90}{$#1$}}{%
    \expandafter\upangletext#3\relax}}%
  \fi
}
\def\upangletext#1#2\relax{\small\setstackgap{L}{\myvgap}%
  \def\myslant{\kern\myhkern#1}\upangletextB#2\relax}
\makeatletter
\def\upangletextB#1#2\relax{%
  \global\protected@edef\myslant{\tllap{\myslant}\kern\myhkern#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\myslant\else\upangletextB#2\relax\fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$(\diagunder{A}{alpha},\diagunder{B}{beta})$ versus
$(\diagunder[]{A}{alpha},\diagunder[]{B}{beta})$

$(\diagover{A}{alpha},\diagover{B}{beta})$ versus
$(\diagover[]{A}{alpha},\diagover[]{B}{beta})$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Adapting to the full MWE of the OP (some changes to my logic had to occur because my MWE above was stacked in text mode, while the OP's full example was stacked in math mode):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\stackMath
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\scriptstyle#1}
\def\req{\protect\rotatebox{90}{$\scriptstyle=$}}
\def\rne{\protect\rotatebox{90}{$\scriptstyle\ne$}}
\makeatother
\def\myhkern{.3pt}
\def\myvgap{.3\baselineskip}
\def\stacktype{L}
\def\mss#1{\mathrm{\scriptscriptstyle#1}}
\newcommand\diagunder[3][\scriptstyle=]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax%
    \stackunder{\scriptstyle#2}{\expandafter\angletext#3\relax}%
  \else
    \stackunder{\scriptstyle#2}{\stackunder[.7\baselineskip]{%
    \rotatebox{90}{$#1$}}{\expandafter\angletext#3\relax}}%
  \fi
}
\def\angletext#1#2\relax{\setstackgap{L}{\myvgap}%
  \kern\myhkern\mss{#1}\angletextB#2\relax}
\def\angletextB#1#2\relax{%
  \brlap{\kern\myhkern\mss{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\angletextB#2\relax\fi}%
}
\newcommand\diagover[3][\scriptstyle=]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax%
    \stackon{\scriptstyle#2}{\expandafter\upangletext#3\relax}%
  \else
    \stackon{\scriptstyle#2}{\stackon[.7\baselineskip]{\rotatebox{90}{$#1$}}{%
    \expandafter\upangletext#3\relax}}%
  \fi
}
\def\upangletext#1#2\relax{\setstackgap{L}{\myvgap}%
  \def\myslant{\kern\myhkern\mss{#1}}\upangletextB#2\relax}
\makeatletter
\def\upangletextB#1#2\relax{%
  \global\protected@edef\myslant{\tllap{\myslant}\kern\myhkern\mss{#1}}%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\myslant\else\upangletextB#2\relax\fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{.6\baselineskip}\setstacktabulargap{0pt}\TABbinary
\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{
 (&\diagover{A}{alpha}& , &\diagover{B}{beta}&) \hspace{1mm}= \hspace{1mm} F\\
 &\rne&\\ &\mathclap{(\diagunder[]{D}{delta} , B)}&}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And if you decided that you wanted to do it in `\textstyle` rather than `\scriptstyle` (since a lot of the math spacing, e.g. around `=` is more natural), then here is your MWE converted for that.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\stackMath
\makeatletter
\def\req{\protect\rotatebox{90}{$=$}}
\def\rne{\protect\rotatebox{90}{$\ne$}}
\makeatother
\def\myhkern{.3pt}
\def\myvgap{.3\baselineskip}
\def\stacktype{L}
\def\mss#1{\mathrm{\scriptscriptstyle#1}}
\newcommand\diagunder[3][=]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax%
    \stackunder[.8\baselineskip]{#2}{\expandafter\angletext#3\relax}%
  \else
    \stackunder[.8\baselineskip]{#2}{\stackunder[.8\baselineskip]{%
    \rotatebox{90}{$#1$}}{\expandafter\angletext#3\relax}}%
  \fi
}
\def\angletext#1#2\relax{\setstackgap{L}{\myvgap}%
  \kern\myhkern\mss{#1}\angletextB#2\relax}
\def\angletextB#1#2\relax{%
  \brlap{\kern\myhkern\mss{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\angletextB#2\relax\fi}%
}
\newcommand\diagover[3][=]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax%
    \stackon[.8\baselineskip]{#2}{\expandafter\upangletext#3\relax}%
  \else
    \stackon[.8\baselineskip]{#2}{\stackon[.8\baselineskip]{\rotatebox{90}{$#1$}}{%
    \expandafter\upangletext#3\relax}}%
  \fi
}
\def\upangletext#1#2\relax{\setstackgap{L}{\myvgap}%
  \def\myslant{\kern\myhkern\mss{#1}}\upangletextB#2\relax}
\makeatletter
\def\upangletextB#1#2\relax{%
  \global\protected@edef\myslant{\tllap{\myslant}\kern\myhkern\mss{#1}}%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\myslant\else\upangletextB#2\relax\fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{.85\baselineskip}\setstacktabulargap{0pt}\TABbinary
\tabularCenterstack{rcl}{
 (&\diagover{A}{alpha}& , \diagover{B}{beta}) = F\\
 &\rne&\\ &\mathclap{(\diagunder[]{D}{delta} , B)}&}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1) Can the equality sign be made shorter vertically, to equal in height the rotated ordinary equality sign? 2) I think, also, there needs to be a parameter to space the letters horizontally in each diagonal: when writing by hand, the letters are place CLOSER together horizontally to make it look better (I agree with you, it looks strange) in addition to the vertical displacement which is already presently controlled. 3) Is this a version of the diagonal without the equality sign, so that it can also be used with the general stacks setup in the MWE? (E.g., A is alpha and a complex number.)

Comment: @GuidoJorg Please see my revision to try to accommodate your wishes.

Comment: @GuidoJorg Please see my REEDIT, which allows bot `\diagover` and `\diagunder`.

Comment: The over `B` equal sign seams to be a little left in the last example ;-) All this work diserve a bounty !

Comment: @Tarass Indeed, the equal is shifted only because it was a pure rotation of the original `=`.  There needs to be a shift to compensate, which I leave to the OP... or maybe I'll get to it.

Comment: I wonder in front of your code, for me all those expandafter, relax, kern are a kind of magic. I have regrets I never took time to learn that.

Comment: @Tarass The `\expandafter` just expands the diag argument before processing it, which allows one to pass a macro to the routine, instead of just plain text.  I tend to use `\relax` as an end-of-string to my parsing routines, because it stops argument expansion, but moreover, it does nothing, and so if the logic ends up printing one out, no harm done.  Also, since it is not a typical character in your data, it is not likely to get confused over where the actual end of the data is (e.g., if I made `x` the end of string character, then any `x` in the data would confuse the parsing routine).

Comment: @Tarass ...Since `\ifx` does a comparison without expansion, the test `\ifx\relax#1\relax...` will only be true if `#1` is empty, in which case nothing stray is printed out.  But if `#1` is anything other than empty or `\relax`, the test will be false, and the `\else` clause will be executed.  If `#1` happens to be `\relax`, the test is true, but only the third `\relax` gets executed and does...nothing.  Easy, huh?

Comment: I knew this trick ! ;-) David Carlisle explained it to me, as I asked how to test an empty string. But it failed on something complex or maybe I made something wrong, now I use ifthenelse and in some simple case ifnum.

Comment: I was traveling (got back today). I agree. All this work by Steven does deserve a bounty :) Made one. Also I gave more rep, via +1 per comment, to Steven and also to Tarass, who submitted a nice answer too :)

Comment: @GuidoJorg Does +1 on a comment affect reputation?

Answer (score 10):

Fun and reccursive :

```
    $(\setstackgap{S}{-1pt}
    \DiagUnder<$(\DiagUnder{D}{delta},B)$>{
        \setstackgap{S}{3pt}%
        \DiagUnder<\NEgal>{\DiagOn<\Egal>{A}{alfpha}}{}
    }{},\DiagOn<\NEgal>{B}{beta})=F$
```

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring,ifthen,stackengine,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\R{String}
\def\N{0}

\newsavebox{\MyBox}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\DiagUnder}{
    d<>
    O{(-45:.8em)}
    m
    m
    D<>{l}
    }{%
    \def\stackalignment{#5}%
    \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
    \def\@R{#4}%
    \def\@N{0}%
    \savebox\MyBox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(x0),
        every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
        \node (x0) at (0,-.16) {} ;         
        \whiledo{\NOT\equal{\@R}{}}{%
            \StrLeft{\@R}{1}[\@L]
            \StrGobbleLeft{\@R}{1}[\@R]
        \node at ($(x0) + \@N*#2 $) {\strut\@L} ;
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\@N{\@N+1}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    }
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% sans
        \stackunder{$#3$}{\hspace{-3pt}\usebox{\MyBox}}%
        }{% avec
        \def\stackalignment{c}%
        \stackunder{$#3$}{%
            \def\stackalignment{l}%
            \setstackgap{S}{1pt}%
            \stackunder{%       
            \makebox[1em]{#1}}{\hspace{-2pt}\usebox{\MyBox}}}%
        }%
    }%

\NewDocumentCommand{\DiagOn}{
    d<>
    O{(-45:.8em)}
    m
    m
    D<>{r}
    }{%
    \def\stackalignment{#5}%
    \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
    \setstackgap{S}{2pt}
    \def\@R{#4}%
    \def\@N{0}%
    \savebox\MyBox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(x0),
        every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]
        \node (x0) at (0,.16) {} ;         
        \whiledo{\NOT\equal{\@R}{}}{%
            \StrLeft{\@R}{1}[\@L]
            \StrGobbleLeft{\@R}{1}[\@R]
        \node at ($(x0) + \@N*#2 $) {\strut\@L} ;
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\@N{\@N+1}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    }
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% sans
        \stackon{$#3$}{\hspace{-2pt}\usebox{\MyBox}}%
        }{% avec
        \def\stackalignment{c}%
        \stackon{$#3$}{%
            \def\stackalignment{r}%
            \setstackgap{S}{-1pt}%
            \stackon{%      
            \makebox[1em]{#1}}{\usebox{\MyBox}}}%
        }%
    }%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Egal}{\,\rotatebox{90}{$=$}}
\newcommand{\NEgal}{\rotatebox{90}{$\neq$}}

\begin{document}
Bob$(\DiagUnder<\Egal>{A}{Diagonale},
    \DiagUnder<\NEgal>[(-35:.9em)]{B}{Diagonale},
    \DiagUnder[(-.2,.1)]{C}{Diagonale},
    \DiagOn<\Egal>{D}{Diagonale},
    \DiagOn<\NEgal>[(115:-.9em)]{E}{Diagonale},
    \DiagOn[(.2,.1)]{F}{Diagonale}<l>)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer too. Wish I could accept both answers :)